# Nginx rate limit isn't working for POST method

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have this configuration for my application.

```
geo $limit {
default 1;
x.x.0.0/16 0;
}

map $limit $limit_key {
0 "";
1 $binary_remote_addr;
}

limit_req_zone $limit_key zone=mylimit:40m rate=70r/s;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimt2:20m rate=2r/m;

server {
listen 8080;
listen [::]:8080;

    location ~* /api/v3/imprints/.*/testTriangles.* {
        limit_req zone=mylimit2;
        limit_req_status 429;
        limit_req_log_level notice;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host data.port.mywebsite.com;
    }
    
    location / {
        limit_req zone=mylimit;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host data.port.mywebsite.com;
        client_max_body_size 40M;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
    }

}
```

I successfully get 429 if I sent more than 2 GET requests. But for POST method nginx do nothing.
Anyone come accross this kind of issue? How to debug that issue?

I have tried this map

`map $request_method $limit_key2 {     default         "";     POST            $binary_remote_addr; }`

but no luck

Comment: Hi, @srghma do you know the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

We're using signal science along with nginx. That caused the issue. Adding this line  `sigsci_handler_phase access;` in nginx.conf file solved the issue.